# Using a custom chai method assertion with chai-as-promised

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I want to add a custom assertion/method like this:

```js
chai.use(function (chai, utils) {
  var Assertion = chai.Assertion;
  Assertion.addMethod("convertToStringEqual", function (input) {
    new Assertion(this._obj.toString()).to.equal(input.toString());
  });
});
```

However I want to be able to use it with `chai-as-promised` like so:

`Promise.resolve(2 + 2).should.eventually.convertToStringEqual(4);`

But when I run this example, I see this error:

`AssertionError: expected '[object Promise]' to equal '4'`

This is because `chai-as-promised` is not resolving that promise with `eventually` before passing it to `convertToStringEqual`.

How can I get `chai-as-promised` await that promise before passing it to my custom assertion method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your custom plugin firstly, then, add the `chai-as-promise`. Related to the order of loading plugins.

From the [#installation-and-setup](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised#installation-and-setup)

> **Note when using other Chai plugins**: Chai as Promised finds all currently-registered asserters and promisifies them, at the time it is installed. **Thus, you should install Chai as Promised last**, after any other Chai plugins, if you expect their asserters to be promisified.

E.g.

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(function(chai, utils) {
  var Assertion = chai.Assertion;
  Assertion.addMethod('convertToStringEqual', function(input) {
    new Assertion(this._obj.toString()).to.equal(input.toString());
  });
});
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

describe('65418901', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    return Promise.resolve(2 + 2).should.eventually.convertToStringEqual(4);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  65418901
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (52ms)
```

But, load the plugins like this will not work:

```js
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.use(function(chai, utils) {
  var Assertion = chai.Assertion;
  Assertion.addMethod('convertToStringEqual', function(input) {
    new Assertion(this._obj.toString()).to.equal(input.toString());
  });
});
chai.should();
```

Comment: Huh I swear I was doing it in that order earlier but I guess not! Thanks for your help, working perfectly now!

Comment: Oh the issue I was having was that i was running chai.use(function....) in every test I had when it only needed to be set once.